# How to gray-out non-editable cell in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to gray non-editable cell in JTable.
I'm using such TableCellRenderer:

```
TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
column.setCellRenderer(new GrayableCheckboxCellRenderer());

public class GrayableCheckboxCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int vRowIndex, int vColIndex) {           
            boolean editable = isEditable(vRowIndex, vColIndex);
        setBackground(editable ? UIManager.getColor("Label.background") : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        setSelected((Boolean) value);
                if (isSelected) {
                    // TODO: cell (and perhaps other cells) are selected, need to highlight it
                }
        return this;
    }
    // perfomance
    protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {}
    public void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, boolean oldValue, boolean newValue) {}
    public void revalidate() {}
    public void validate() {}
}
```

This works but with one annoying artefact:
Initially "checkbox" is "left-arranged", when I press left mouse button it moves to "center-arranged" and when I release mouse button it moves back to "left-arranged".

How to avoid such annoying artefact and probably there are better simpler solution for my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return an instance of `GrayableCheckboxCellRenderer` in a `TableCellEditor`.

Addendum: Aesthetically, you may want to condition the renderer's and editor's colors based on the [defaults](http://nadeausoftware.com/node/85) provided by the current Look & Feel, for example:

```
Color hilite = UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionBackground");
```

Comment: There's a related example [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).

Comment: example works. We are using custom CellRenderer there. When some line in table is selected by user it should be highlighted (in all columns). But it is highlighted in all columns except those columns, that use custom CellRenderer and this is still very ugly...

Comment: You may want to alter the UIManager defaults; more above.

Answer (score 5):

simpliest way by using preparedRenderer

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class Forum {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    private JPanel fatherCenter = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane();
    private myTableModel tableModel;
    private JTable dialogTable;
    private ListSelectionModel lsDialog;

    private void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        tableModel = new myTableModel();
        dialogTable = new JTable(tableModel) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                JComponent jc = (JComponent) comp;//for Custom JComponent
                if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                    int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    boolean type = (Boolean) getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 2);
                    boolean type1 = (Boolean) getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 3);
                    boolean type2 = (Boolean) getModel().isCellEditable(row, column);
                    comp.setForeground(Color.black);
                    if ((type) && (!type1)) {
                        comp.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                    } else if ((!type) && (type1)) {
                        comp.setBackground(Color.orange);
                    } else if ((!type) || (!type1)) {
                        comp.setBackground(Color.red);
                    //} else if ((!type2)) {
                        //comp.setForeground(Color.red);
                        //comp.setBackground(Color.magenta);
                    } else {
                        comp.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? getBackground() : getBackground().darker());
                    }
                    dialogTable.convertRowIndexToView(0);
                } else {
                    comp.setForeground(Color.blue);
                    comp.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                }
                    if (!isCellEditable(row, column)) {
                    comp.setForeground(Color.red);
                    comp.setBackground(Color.magenta);
                }
                return comp;
            }
        };
        tableScroll = new JScrollPane(dialogTable, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        tableScroll.setBorder(null);
        dialogTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        dialogTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        lsDialog = dialogTable.getSelectionModel();
        dialogTable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
        dialogTable.setRowHeight(20);
        dialogTable.setRowMargin(2);
        fatherCenter = new JPanel();
        fatherCenter.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        fatherCenter.add(tableScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(fatherCenter);
    }

    private void addData() {
        Runnable doRun1 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                tableModel.resetTable();
                Vector<String> tbl = new Vector<String>();
                Vector<Object> tbl1 = new Vector<Object>();
                Random rnd = new Random();
                tbl.add("Integer");
                tbl.add("Double");
                tbl.add("Boolean");
                tbl.add("Boolean");
                tbl.add("String");
                tableModel.setColumnNames(tbl);
                for (int row = 0; row < 30; row++) {
                    tbl1 = null;
                    tbl1 = new Vector<Object>();
                    tbl1.addElement(row + 1);
                    tbl1.addElement(rnd.nextInt(25) + 3.14);
                    tbl1.addElement((row % 3 == 0) ? false : true);
                    tbl1.addElement((row % 5 == 0) ? false : true);
                    if (row % 7 == 0) {
                        tbl1.add(("Canc"));
                    } else if (row % 6 == 0) {
                        tbl1.add(("Del"));
                    } else {
                        tbl1.add(("New"));
                    }
                    tableModel.addRow(tbl1);
                }
                addTableListener();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun1);
    }

    private void addTableListener() {
        tableModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
                if (tme.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
                    System.out.println("Cell " + tme.getFirstRow() + ", "
                            + tme.getColumn() + " changed. The new value: "
                            + tableModel.getValueAt(tme.getFirstRow(),
                            tme.getColumn()));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        addData();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 646));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Forum osFrame = new Forum();
    }

    public Forum() {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private class myTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Vector<Vector<Object>> data;
        private Vector<String> colNames;
        private boolean[] _columnsVisible = {true, true, true, true, true};

        myTableModel() {
            this.colNames = new Vector<String>();
            this.data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        }

        myTableModel(Vector<String> colnames) {
            this.colNames = colnames;
            this.data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

        }

        public void resetTable() {
            this.colNames.removeAllElements();
            this.data.removeAllElements();

        }

        public void setColumnNames(Vector<String> colNames) {
            this.colNames = colNames;
            this.fireTableStructureChanged();
        }

        public void addRow(Vector<Object> data) {
            this.data.add(data);
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
            this.fireTableStructureChanged();
        }

        public void removeRowAt(int row) {
            this.data.removeElementAt(row);
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return this.colNames.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colNum) {
            switch (colNum) {
                case 0:
                    return Integer.class;
                case 1:
                    return Double.class;
                case 2:
                    return Boolean.class;
                case 3:
                    return Boolean.class;
                default:
                    return String.class;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int colNum) {
            switch (colNum) {
                case 2:
                    return false;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int colNum) {
            return this.colNames.get(colNum);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return this.data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            Vector<Object> value = this.data.get(row);
            return value.get(col);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object newVal, int row, int col) {
            Vector<Object> aRow = data.elementAt(row);
            aRow.remove(col);
            aRow.insertElementAt(newVal, col);
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

        public void setColumnVisible(int index, boolean visible) {
            this._columnsVisible[index] = visible;
            this.fireTableStructureChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good to know; I though a matching editor was the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Just explicitly setting the alignment in the 'getTableCellRendererComponent()' method solves the problem. Add the below line before returning from the method.

```
 setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```