# Use JTable rowFilter for highliting rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, filtering, rowfilter

I am currenlty using the JTable rowFilter for filtering my rows. The filter hide lines which does not follow the configured pattern.
I wish to know if it's possible to use the rowFilter for changing the color or other of the result ? By example the line which follows the configured pattern are colored in red and other in white.

Thank you
Sylvain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing complicated. For `String Instance`, I would suggest to start with [prepareRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html). There you can set lots of parameters, as shown in [RowFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650734/how-to-gray-out-non-editable-cell-in-jtable/6656279#6656279) based on camickr's [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) :-) Don't forget to set `int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);`

and my question about [similair issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410839/highlights-substring-in-the-tablecells-which-is-using-for-jtable-filetering)

Answer (score 1):

For those approaches I would recommend using SwingX Libraries. Their JXTable can by default work with highlighter- and filterpipelines. The highlighter can also highlight by a given pattern.

Here an example from [R.J. Lorimer](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91834162.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the appearance of a row you'd need to provide your own cell renderer which then could apply the same checks as your row filter.